# If $K = \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ where $\alpha^n \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and $n$ is the minimal such $n$. Does this imply that $[K : \mathbb{F}_p] = n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $K = \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ where $\alpha^n \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and $n$ is the minimal such $n$. Does this imply that $[K : \mathbb{F}_p] = n$?

If not, is there a condition on $\alpha$ where this is the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not imply that $[K:\mathbb{F}_p]=n$.

Let $[K:\mathbb{F}_p]=d$. We can choose an $\alpha\in K$ such that $\alpha$ generates the multiplicative group $K^\times$, so that the smallest $s$ such that $\alpha^s=1$ is $s=p^d-1$, and therefore the smallest $n$ such that $\alpha^n\in\mathbb{F}_p$ has to be $n\geq \frac{p^d-1}{p-1}$, but in general we have that 
$$\frac{p^d-1}{p-1}> d$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\mathbb{F}_2$. Let $x^2 + x + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$, a irreducible polynomial. Let $\theta$ be a root of this polynomial (in the algebraic closure). Then $\mathbb{F}_2[\theta]$ is a degree 2 extension. However $\theta^2 = \theta + 1 \notin \mathbb{F}_2$, since $\theta^2 + \theta + 1 = 0$.

Comment: This is giving a counterexample for the opposite direction of implication to the one the question is about, isn't it?

Comment: @dbaupp $\theta^3 = \theta(\theta^2) = \theta(\theta +  1) = \theta^2 + \theta = 1 \in \mathbb{F}_2$. $3$ is minimal but the extension is degree $2$.

Comment: It is also a counterexample for the converse.

Comment: Oh, yeah, of course. Thanks for explaining :)